# Combine two arrays and keep the array name as the key in the newly combined array

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays, `$array1` and `$array2`. When combining the two arrays, the expected output is to combine both arrays based on their keys, and keep the array name as the key. I'm using `array_merge_recursive($array1,$array2);` which combines the two arrays, but keeping the array name as the key does not work with this.

```
$array1 = array(
'mobile' => array(
    array('item' => 'apple','price' => 4),
    array('item' => 'nokia','price' => 39),
    array('item' => 'samsung','price' => 8)
  ),
  'tv' => array(
     array('item' => 'LG','price' => 39),
     array( 'item' => 'max', 'price' => 8 ),
     array('item' => 'diaken','price' => 3 )
  )
) ;

$array2 = array(
'mobile' => array(
     array('item' => 'HTC','price' => 4 ),
    array('item' => 'OnePlus' ,'price' => 39),
     array ('item' => 'Nexus','price' => 8 )
  ),
'tv' => array( 
    array('item' => 'LG','price' => 39),
    array('item' => 'Panasonic','price' => 8 ),
    array('item' => 'Toshiba' ,'price' => 3 )
  )
);
```

The output should be:

```
array(
'mobile' => array(
  'array1' => array(
    '0' => array('item' => 'apple','price' => 4),
    '1' => array('item' => 'nokia','price' => 39),
    '2' => array('item' => 'samsung','price' => 8),
  )
  'array2' => array (
    '0' => array('item' => 'HTC','price' => 4),
    '1' => array('item' => 'OnePlus','price' => 39),
    '2' => array('item' => 'Nexus','price' => 8)
    )  
),
'tv' => array( 
  'array1' => array( 
    '0' => array('item' => 'LG','price' => 39),
    '1' => array('item' => 'max','price' => 8),
    '2' => array('item' => 'diaken','price' => 3)
    ),
    'array2' => array(
    '0' => array('item' => 'LG','price' => 39),
    '1' => array('item' => 'max','price' => 8),
    '2' => array('item' => 'diaken','price' => 3)
    )  
  )
)
```

I used `array_merge_recursive($array1,$array2);`, and instead of getting the above, I get the following:

```
    Array
(
   'mobile' => Array
        (
            Array('item' => 'apple','price' => 4),
            Array('item' => 'nokia','price' => 39),
            Array('item' => 'samsung','price' => 8),
            Array('item' => 'HTC','price' => 4 ),
            Array('item' => 'OnePlus' ,'price' => 39),
            Array ('item' => 'Nexus','price' => 8 ),

        )

    'tv' => Array
        (
            Array('item' => 'LG','price' => 39),
            Array( 'item' => 'max', 'price' => 8 ),
            Array('item' => 'diaken','price' => 3 ),
            Array ('item' => 'LG','price' => 39),
            Array('item' => 'Panasonic','price' => 8 ),
            Array('item' => 'Toshiba' ,'price' => 3 )

        )

)
```

Comment: You must write your own loop logic for this.

Comment: Do you always have "mobile" and "tv" keys or is there going to be more/less of these?

Comment: @Scuzzy keys are dynamic so could be more/less

Comment: how about `$array1` and `$array2`? only two of those?

Comment: @Scuzzy only two $array1 and $array2

Comment: When submitting code it would be nice if your had the syntax correct.  Your arrays cause errors when copied.  Also could you think of any more ways to waste vertical and horizontal space i.e. more line feeds and indentation.   It would be nice not to have to scroll for so little information.  Hate your style.  A lot.

Comment: @Misunderstood yes i understand but thing is that code was copied from browser while doing `print_r` . now i have changed it do look at it

Comment: var_export does a little better at formatting than print_r.  From var_export I can copy and paste into code and it does not generate errors.  I fixed it.  I don't know why it annoys me so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whilst I don't know how you're going to automate the "discovery" of your array soruces, it should be as simple as this:

```
$array = array();
$array['mobile'] = array();
$array['mobile'][] = $array1['mobile'];
$array['mobile'][] = $array2['mobile'];
$array['tv'] = array();
$array['tv'][] = $array1['tv'];
$array['tv'][] = $array2['tv'];
```

---

```
// Using the array keys as the worker
$array = array();
foreach( array_keys( array_merge( $array1, $array2 ) ) as $key )
{
  $array[$key] = array();
  $array[$key][] = $array1[$key];
  $array[$key][] = $array2[$key];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first array

```
    $array1 = array
(
    'mobile' => array
        (
            '0' => array
                (
                    'item' => 'apple',
                    'price' => 4
                ),
            '1' => array
                (
                    'item' => 'nokia',
                    'price' => 39
                ),
            '2' => array
                (
                    'item' => 'samsung',
                    'price' => 8
                ),
        ),

    'tv' => array
        (
            '0' => array
                (
                    'item' => 'LG',
                    'price' => 39
                ),
            '1' => array
                (
                    'item' => 'max',
                    'price' => 8
                ),
            '2' => array
                (
                    'item' => 'diaken',
                    'price' => 3
                ),
        )
) ;
```

second array

```
    $array2 = array
(
    'mobile' => array
        (
            '0' => array
                (
                    'item' => 'HTC',
                    'price' => 4
                ),
            '1' => array
                (
                    'item' => 'OnePlus',
                    'price' => 39
                ),
            '2' => array
                (
                    'item' => 'Nexus',
                    'price' => 8
                ),
        ),
    'tv' => array
        (
            '0' => array
                (
                    'item' => 'LG',
                    'price' => 39
                ),
            '1' => array
                (
                    'item' => 'Panasonic',
                    'price' => 8
                ),
            '2' => array
                (
                    'item' => 'Toshiba',
                    'price' => 3
                ),
        )
);
```

marge two array and print result

```
    $array['mobile']['array1'] = $array1['mobile'];
    $array['mobile']['array2'] = $array2['mobile'];
    $array['tv']['array1'] = $array1['tv'];
    $array['tv']['array2'] = $array2['tv'];
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($array);
    echo '</pre>';
```

output

```
    Array
    (
[mobile] => Array
    (
        [array1] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [item] => apple
                        [price] => 4
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [item] => nokia
                        [price] => 39
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [item] => samsung
                        [price] => 8
                    )

            )

        [array2] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [item] => HTC
                        [price] => 4
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [item] => OnePlus
                        [price] => 39
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [item] => Nexus
                        [price] => 8
                    )

            )

    )

[tv] => Array
    (
        [array1] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [item] => LG
                        [price] => 39
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [item] => max
                        [price] => 8
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [item] => diaken
                        [price] => 3
                    )

            )

        [array2] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [item] => LG
                        [price] => 39
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [item] => Panasonic
                        [price] => 8
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [item] => Toshiba
                        [price] => 3
                    )

            )

    )
```

)

Answer (score 0):

Please check below code if array1 and array2 are fixed as per your above comment

```
$array_keys = array_keys( array_merge( $array1, $array2));

$final_array = array();
foreach($array_keys as $akey)
{
    if(array_key_exists($akey, $array1))
        $final_array[$akey]['array1'] = $array1[$akey];

    if(array_key_exists($akey, $array2))
        $final_array[$akey]['array2'] = $array2[$akey];
}
echo "<pre>";
    print_r($final_array);
echo "</pre>";
```

Input code:

```
$array1 = array(
'mobile' => array(
    array('item' => 'apple','price' => 4),
    array('item' => 'nokia','price' => 39),
    array('item' => 'samsung','price' => 8)
  ),
  'tv' => array(
     array('item' => 'LG','price' => 39),
     array( 'item' => 'max', 'price' => 8 ),
     array('item' => 'diaken','price' => 3 )
  )
) ;
$array2 = array (
  'mobile' => array (
    0 => array ('item' =>'HTC','price' => 4,),
    1 => array ('item' =>'OnePlus','price' => 39,),
    2 => array ('item' =>'Nexus','price' => 8,)
  ),
  'tv' => array (
    0 => array ('item' =>'LG','price' => 39,),
    1 => array ('item' =>'Panasonic','price' => 8,),
    2 => array ('item' =>'Toshiba','price' => 3)
  )
);
```

**o/p:**

```
Array
(
    [mobile] => Array
        (
            [array1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [item] => apple
                            [price] => 4
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [item] => nokia
                            [price] => 39
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [item] => samsung
                            [price] => 8
                        )

                )

            [array2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [item] => HTC
                            [price] => 4
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [item] => OnePlus
                            [price] => 39
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [item] => Nexus
                            [price] => 8
                        )

                )

        )

    [tv] => Array
        (
            [array1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [item] => LG
                            [price] => 39
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [item] => max
                            [price] => 8
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [item] => diaken
                            [price] => 3
                        )

                )

            [array2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [item] => LG
                            [price] => 39
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [item] => Panasonic
                            [price] => 8
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [item] => Toshiba
                            [price] => 3
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Comment: final_array has repeating keys in it. for e.g it gives two array keys as array1 and array 2 but again in array2 keys there is array1 & array2 which is not expected o/p

Comment: it is not showing any repeating key to me this o/p. It shows me same as your expected o/p. I had used your array sample for demo and it works same as your expectation.

Answer (score 0):

i would like to do simply do following --

```
// loop through first array 
$tempArray = [];
foreach($array1 as $key=>$object)
{
    $tempArray[$key] = [];
     array_push($tempArray[$key], $object);
     array_push($tempArray[$key],$array2[$key]);
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($tempArray);
echo '</pre>';
```

> this will give you exact output what you want. Irrespective  of how many keys exists in the array. You need to determine on which array loop should be imposed.

Comment: feel free to have queries .... and let me know whether this works for you or not.